# How to reload a page after clicked ok using sweetalert

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sweetalert

Hello I have a code using sweetalert

```
swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success")
```

this code will pop-up a message and has a button okay, what I like to do is I want to refresh the page after I click the okay button.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can try this, it works for me.

```
swal({
       title: "Good job", 
       text: "You clicked the button!", 
       type: "success"
     },
   function(){ 
       location.reload();
   }
);
```

Answer (score 28):

The answer from Yoshioka did not work for me, I did this and it worked perfectly:

```
swal({title: "Good job", text: "You clicked the button!", type: 
"success"}).then(function(){ 
   location.reload();
   }
);
```

Comment: Yoshioka's answer didn't work for me but Leo thanks it woking

Answer (score 16):

Use the callback function...

```
Swal.fire({
  // Swal Setting's
}).then((result) => {
  // Reload the Page
  location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

For Sweet Alert 2, this will work.

```
swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success").then(function(){
    location.reload();
});
```

As you can see [migration guide](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/wiki/Migration-from-SweetAlert-to-SweetAlert2#3-modal-with-input-field)

Sweet Alert 2 uses [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Answer (score 5):

You can check confirm by this:

```
swal({
  title: "Good job",
  text: "You clicked the button!",
  icon: "success",
  buttons: [
    'NO',
    'YES'
  ],
}).then(function(isConfirm) {
  if (isConfirm) {
    location.reload();
  } else {
    //if no clicked => do something else
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I use sweet alert 2 and this works for me

```
swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!","success").then( () => {
    location.href = 'somepage.html'
})
```

‘’’
The answers making use of location.reload() is going to trigger your form to attempt to resubmit over and over again, thats why you should use location.href instead.

Answer (score 2):

In [Sweet Alert 2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/), there is callback function where you can implement your logic :

```
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Great job',
  text: "You clicked the button!",
  type: 'success',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes'
}).then((result) => {
   if(result){
     // Do Stuff here for success
     location.reload();
   }else{
    // something other stuff
   }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the reference on [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/).

```
Swal.fire(
    {
        title: "Good job", 
        text: "You clicked the button!", 
        type: "success",
        showDenyButton: true,          // In case you want two scenarios 
        denyButtonText: 'ABC',
        showCancelButton: true,        // In case you want two scenarios 
        cancelButtonText:'XYZ'
    }
).then(function (result) {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
        //You can add code here if user pressed ok button
    } else if (result.isDenied) {
        //You can add code here if user pressed deny button
    } else if(result.isDismissed) {
        //You can add code here if user pressed cancel button
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me.

```
Swal.fire('Deleted !!', data.message, 'success').then(() => {
    location.reload();
});
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer. In Sweetalert2 it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
swal({
   title: "Process Completed",
   text: "Data Recorded successfully",
   buttons: true
}).then(function(){
   location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved it with this :

```
swal({title: "Updated!", text: "yourText", type: "success"},function() {
                                location.reload();
     }) // swal end
```

Another way :

```
swal("Updated!","yourText","success",function() {
     location.reload();
}) // swal end
```

Comment: This is very similar to comments above

Comment: i tried from here too. i solved it that way. After that, i thought I should share the way too @Fil